# Direct sum of any two of subspaces gives the whole space

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $n=2k$, prove that there are infinitely many $k$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ such that the direct sum of any two of them is $\mathbb R^n.$

I think we should use induction because for $n=2$ it is very easy: we just choose pairwise unparallel lines from the same plane, but how do we perform an induction step? Or prove it otherwise?

Comment: Hint: you can extend a linearly independent set to a basis.

Answer (score 1):

If $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of dimension $k$ and $2k = n = dim\mathbb{R}^n$ then since they are direct summed:
$$U \cap W = \vec{0}$$
So then let $\{u_1, u_2, ..., u_k\}$ and $\{w_1, w_2, ..., w_k\}$ be bases of $U$ and $W$ respectively. They are linearly independent since their intersection is the zero vector, thus:
$$\{u_1, u_2, ..., u_k, w_1, w_2, ...., w_k\}$$
And its cardinality is $2k = n$ so there are $n$ linearly independent vectors as desired.

Since the underlying field is infinite, we can create infinite subspaces and constantly direct sum them.